# yum-cron equivalent in amazon linux 2

Tags: amazon-ec2

It looks like yum-cron is unavailable in amazon linux 2.X, how can I enable automatic updates?

I'm trying to install both security and non-security updates automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate this util by executing in cron something like:

```
0 0 * * 6 yum upgrade -y
```

This will exec update via `yum` at midnight every Saturday. You can of course tune the schedule per your requirements.
In `cron` you can add `MAILTO` to send mail to someone withe the result of update.

If you want to fully automate the process you can use `needs-restarting` to check if the system need restart and do it.